# What is the difference between a JsonValue and a JsonObject?

Tags: c#, .net, json

What is the difference between a [JsonValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.json.jsonvalue) and a [JsonObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.json.jsonobject)?

I see that JsonValue is the base class for `JsonObject`, `JsonPrimitive` and `JsonArray`. But aren't all of them simply `JsonObject`s?

Comment: Are you using `System.Json.dll` or Json.NET?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski As you can see from the links in the question - System.Json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JsonValue` is , as you said, the base class of the three classes in questions. It is also abstract. This suggests that it represents something *general*. It's a general term.

`JsonObject` *is a kind of* `JsonValue` (since the former inherits from the latter). Which kind? This kind:

```
{ ... }
```

`JsonArray` *is another kind of* `JsonValue`. Which kind? This kind:

```
[ ... ]
```

`JsonPrimitive` is the third kind of `JsonValue`, and it represents the 3 other types of values you can have in JSON - `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`.

Comment: Are you saying that a JsonArray (for example) is _not_ a JsonObject?

Comment: @ispiro Exactly. `JsonArray` specifically refers to `[ ... ]` and `JsonObject` specifically refers to `{ ... }`. `[1,2,3]` is a `JsonArray` with 3 `JsonPrimitive`s inside.